# EF Core 2.1 is updating ID when I am simply Loading and Saving

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

EF Core 2.1 is updating ID when I am simply Loading and Saving values in Database.

Note: I am using Database first approach.

Error : Cannot update identity column 'ID'.

```
 string passportNumber = string.Empty;
    using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext(connectionString))
        {
            using (IDbContextTransaction transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    TLifting Lifting = new TLifting();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PassportNumber))
                    {
                        Lifting = db.TLifting.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    Lifting.Col1 = "TEST"

                    if (Lifting.PassportId == 0)
                    {
                        db.TLifting.Add(Lifting);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Entry(Lifting).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                  
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Entity

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Lifting](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [PassportID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [PassportTypeID]  AS ((5)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Lifting_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PassportID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_T_Lifting] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_Lifting]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__T_Lifting__T_Passport] FOREIGN KEY([PassportID], [PassportTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[T_Passport] ([PassportID], [PassportTypeID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[T_Lifting] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__T_Lifting__T_Passport]
GO
```

Passport and Piping table are having one one relationship and ID column Identity column.

Answer (score 0):

May be following settings would help you:

In `protected override void onModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {}` method, write the below line of code accordingly.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Type>().Property(u => u.ID).Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```

Note: Here `Type` will be class model/object of yours.

Comment: I don't want to ignore the behavior, I just don't EF core to generate update query for ID as I am not updating it

Comment: Okay, then you may try with putting db.Update(lifting).Property(x=>x.ID).IsModified = false; just before db.SaveChanges();

Comment: Thank you @Salahuddin, It does solve the problem ID problem but now a different ID issue coming. But why I should mark it as modified and when I actually did not modify it and why it is automatically marked as modified ?

Comment: Sorry did not get the point on different ID issue that you are facing now ;)

Comment: because I did not explain it. Can you please let me know why EF is marking ID as modified when we did not modify it?

Comment: Anyway you may use like this, db.Entry(Lifting).State = EntityState.Modified; db.Entry(Lifting).Property(x => x.ID).IsModified = false; db.SaveChanges(); It will update but without ID property and hence you might get rid of the new issue you are facing :)